# Observe size of lockfree queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

all

I'm trying to use the boost library's lock free queue data structure.

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
```

However, I found out that these data structure do not support methods to get the number of current entries that these are containing (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html).

What I want is something similar to std::queue::size (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/size).

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: A concurrent data structure doesn't *have* a size. Think about it. Or, if that really upsets you, just consider all concurrent data structures to have size 17.

Comment: @KerrekSB It does have a size, just not one that can be known with total accuracy.

Comment: @MichaelGazonda And that makes its size quite a useless concept.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not at all. Just because the container doesn't report a size with 100% accuracy doesn't mean it's useless. Sometimes it's better to know an approximate size than nothing at all.

Comment: @MichaelGazonda: There is nothing you can do with any value reported as a "size". Any value would be as good as any other.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's silly. You might be interested in whether a queue looks like it's becoming backed up, for example.

Comment: "becoming backed up"? What?

Comment: @KerrekSB No dude. Just no.

Comment: Really appreciating all the splendid arguments being made. "No _dude_" is convincing these days.

Comment: @sehe Stall detection is important; you don't want your queues expanding until all your RAM is used up if you can't consume its elements quickly enough.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not sure what you're responding to. The usual approach with lockfree queues would appear to be fixed-size queueus anyways (which is where tuning comes in). Otherwise you're firmly into (patented?) garbage collected lockfree datastructures (e.g. hazard pointers)

Comment: @sehe: You asked what "becoming backed up" meant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh. Really. So "backed up" means surprising things in English. TIL

Comment: @sehe: c.f. "the freeway is backed up", something I personally wouldn't say but I must concede that many hundreds of millions of English-speakers would!

Comment: @KerrekSB if God wanted us to never use transient information such as size in a concurrent environment, then why has He created `queue::empty`?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to track high/low water marks, have an atomic counter that you increment when you enqueue, and decrement when you dequeue.

You can periodically sample that counter to do any tuning/statistical analysis that you might need.

The queue itself doesn't supply this operation, because you only pay for what you need.

Comment: And just to be sure, there isn't any kind of guarantee that the separately kept counter shows a meaningful number. If there's a large pause between an enqueue and the increment, and no pause between a dequeue and the decrement, you can even have negative sizes. It's all approximate and best effort. At that point you might be better off just keeping two separate, incrementing counters only, one for "work produced" and one for "work consumed", and monitor those.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's meaningful, in the way that statistics can be meaningful, as long as you take sample biases and measurement error into account. Even so, it's probably more useful when deriving smoothed/corrected information from this. Technically, you're spot on of course

Comment: See my edit; for statistics, I'd measure my "ability to keep up", rather than a particular container size. Yes, statistics are very important.

Comment: @KerrekSB: first increment, then enqueue. First dequeue, then decrement. Atomic operations cannot be reordered, right? No negative sizes then.

Comment: @RomanL Depends on de memory ordering. But by default you're right there. Doesn't make the numbers accurate of course. I'd rather have the negatives than the unneeded bias.

Comment: @sehe right, I meant the default sequential consistency. I disagree: negative values make no sense, while positive bias can be interpreted as the operation not fully complete (yet). I am skeptical about the negative values/bias anyway. This would require getting a context switch right in-between those two memory-access operations. This needs to happen quite often to see anything more than an off-by-one which no one really cares about, unless they incorrectly rely on something like `if (counter > 0)`.

Comment: @RomanL Multicore processors do not require context switches for data races to happen. Depending on how the atomic counters are accessed, it's easy to observe inconsistent values from a "third" thread, yes. I think you're right actually that the default `std::memory_order_seq_cst` will not allow net negatives to be observed, indeed. I didn't realize how conservative std::atomic actually is, by default. Good point you made there. (You could argue that the increased barriers do not introduce bias, but they might, if the latencies are tiny; it actually modifies the latency then)